# How to create multiple thumbnails on CKFinder 3?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder, ckfinder3

I am using CKFinder PHP 3.5.3.

When I upload an image, it creates only one default 150x150 thumbnail currently.

I tried the following configuration of a thumbnail on the config.php, but it doesn't work:

```
$config['thumbnails'] = array(
    'enabled'      => true,
    'sizes'        => array(
        array('width' => '150', 'height' => '150', 'quality' => 80),
        array('width' => '300', 'height' => '300', 'quality' => 80),
        array('width' => '500', 'height' => '500', 'quality' => 80),
    ),
    'bmpSupported' => true,
);
```

I would like to create multiple thumbnails such as 150x150, 300x300 and 500x500 when upload an image.

How can I generate multiple thumbnails when I upload an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CKFinder 3 thumbnails of different sizes are generated lazily, on demand. This means the thumbnail of a given size will not be generated until requested by CKFinder's frontend. It's possible to change this behavior with a plugin. [Here](https://gist.github.com/zaak/b6caf97c9f8b7af95f7e04902c286a0e) you can find a plugin I have created that enforces CKFinder to generate all the private thumbnails immediately after the file is uploaded.

Comment: Okay. That's cool. I'll try it and write a comment.

Comment: What is the easiest way to create thumbnails with a special path and file name? For example, if I upload a image named "aa.png" into a "image" directory, how can I create thumbnails in specific locations such as "images/150x150/aa.png", "images/300x300/aa.png" and "images/500x500/aa.png"?